# How to take the size of an ArrayList<double> and set it into a jTextField so i can see it

Tags: java, arraylist, jtextfield

I have this arraylist which is filled with numbers that are added from a text file we open

```
private ArrayList< Double> data = new ArrayList< Double>();
...

if( jfc.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION ) {

    String file = jfc.getSelectedFile().getPath();
    String line = null;
    String[] ch;

    try {   
        FileReader fr = new FileReader( file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        data.clear();
        while( (ligne=br.readLine())!=null ) {
            ch = line.split( ";" );
            for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
                data.add( Double.parseDouble(ch[i]) );  
            }                       
        }

        br.close();             
    }
    catch( IOException ioe ) {
    }           
}
```

How can i put the size of data(data.size()) to show in a jTextField named(jtfN)?
also how can I calculate the average of the data?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the jTextField:

`jtfN.setText(String.valueOf(data.size()))`

Calculate the average:

```
double total = 0;
/* summ all doubles */
for(double d : data) {
    total += d;
}
/* devide by count of doubles */
double average = total / data.size();
```

Comment: Thanks. Just wondering if I were to do for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++){ total+=i;} double average = total/data.size(); why wouldn't it work cause when i tried it gave me a completely different answer.

Comment: Total += I? :) that's the index! It's data.get(I)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`String.valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28int%29):

`jtfN.setText(String.valueOf(data.size()));`

To calculate the average of data :

1. Create a variable to hold the sum of the numbers in data
2. Loop through data and add each number to sum
3. Divide sum by the size of data

Answer (score 0):

> How can i put the size of data(data.size()) to show in a jTextField
>   named(jtfN)?

```
jtfN.setText(String.valueOf(this.data.size()));
```

> also how can I calculate the average of the data?

It's the sum of all the values in the list divided by the size of the list.